# Comparing fields of two files in awk

Tags: awk

I want to compare two fields of two files, such as follows:

Compare the 2nd filed of file one with the 1st field of file two, print the match (even if the match is repeated) and all the columns of file one and two.

File 1:

```
 G4   b45  3  4
 G4   b45  1  3
 G3   b23  2  2
 G3   b22  2  6
 G3   b22  2  4
```

File 2:

```
 b45  a  b  c
 b64  d  e  f  
 b23  g  h  i
 b22  j  k  l
 b20  m  n  o
```

Output:

```
 G4   b45  a  b  c  3  4
 G4   b45  a  b  c  1  3
 G3   b23  g  h  i  2  2
 G3   b22  j  k  l  2  6
 G3   b22  j  k  l  2  4
```

I have tried this with the following awk command using associative arrays:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {array1[$2] = $1 ; arrayrest[$2] = substr($0, index($0, $2)); next}($1 in array1) {print array1[$1] "\t" $0 "\t" arrayrest[$1]}' file1 file2
```

But there are two problems:

1. It does not print the lines if the match is repeated while I want them to be printed.
2. It repeats the first field of file two in the output.

How could I make this awk command work nicely? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with `join`? `join -1 2 -2 1 <(sort f1) <(sort f2)` gives almost this output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite the exact output formatting you want but the right output contents.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$1]=$0; next} ($2 in seen) {$2=seen[$2]}7' file2 file1
```

Add `| column -t` to get more consistent column spacing.

Comment: +1 for knowing I am not alone to use right index finger (`7`) much more than the left little finger (`1`)  :-D  However it could be `awk 'FNR==NR{..}($2 in seen) && $2=seen[$2]'`

Comment: @Kent Hah! Is that why you do it? I adopted it because I think it makes it look both more and less "magical" which (hopefully) makes people ask about it.

Comment: I put the OFS="\t" to get a tab between columns. So, to make sure I understand, you have put the first column of the second file as the key of the "seen" array and as its value, you have given to it all the columns of the second file, is it correct? Then you are checking if column 2 of the first file exists in the keys of the "seen" array, and if so, you print the whole file one with its second column being the second column of the second file. Is that right? And now, indeed, 7 is a magical term for me? could you please explain it if possible?

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, the most frequent keystroke for my left little finger is the `ESC`, just next to the `1` on my keyboard.

Comment: @Kent I've shied away from using pattern assignments like that for two reasons. I've been bitten a few times by the result being `0` or `""` and awk considering that false and because I think it is more confusing to people who aren't as familiar with awk. But you are right in this case that certainly seems like it would work safely.

Comment: @user1759438 Yes, key `seen` off the collating field (`$1` in the second file). Do it in this order because we need the duplicates from `file1` (and presumably `file2` can't have any). Then if a line in `file1` has a matching key in field two replace that field with the entirety of the line from `seen`. Any truth-y pattern will trigger its matching action block. The default action block is `{print}`. awk treats non-zero integers as truth-y so `7` is short for `7{print}` which is `TRUE{print}`. (Similarly the default pattern is true so `{print $2}` is short for `TRUE{print $2}`, etc.

Comment: Sorry, this part {$2=seen[$2]}, I think I still don't understand it. So, we created 'seen' array with $1 of the second file as its keys. After executing the condition, we set the keys of the 'seen' array to the second field of the file 2, is that so? I would never be able to do it on my own this part as I don't understand it completely.

Comment: @user1759438 `$2=seen[$2]` is setting the second field of the current line to the value of the `seen` table that matches that collating key. For a line `G4   b45  3  4` that will replace `b45` with the value of the line saved in `seen` under the `b45` key (i.e. the line `b45  a  b  c` from `file2`).

Comment: I see, that's much more clear. I think I understood it well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kent No need to search for `$2` in `seen` at all, if it isn't there then `$2=seen[$2]` wont print anyway.Unless of course it can contain 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

This should be simple and clear to u:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {n[$2]=$0} {if ($1 in n) print n[$1],$2,$3,$4}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

small awk

```
awk '{x[$1]=$0}$2=x[$2]' f2 f1
```

If $1 and $2 can contain the same value

```
 awk '{x[$1]=$0}FNR!=NR&&$2=x[$2]' f2 f1
```

#### output

```
G4  b45  a  b  c 3 4
G4  b45  a  b  c 1 3
G3  b23  g  h  i 2 2
G3  b22  j  k  l 2 6
G3  b22  j  k  l 2 4
```

Comment: Clever. But this doesn't work if any second field of `f2` matches any previous first field in that file (I have no idea if that is possible for this data or not). Adding `FNR==NR` and `next` fixes that though. It also fails if any line in `f2` is just `0` but that seems unlikely for this data.

Comment: @EtanReisner I was using the fact that $1 and $2 of file1 are unlikely to contain the same values(judging from the sample). Also they appeared to have a character before the number on each so 0 shouldn't have been  a problem. Obviously this isn't a very general method though and yours would be better suited to a wider array of problems.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you chose `ARGIND<2` instead of `FNR==NR` for that guard? Also wouldn't it make more sense to guard the second pattern (i.e. `ARGIND>=2&&$2=x[$2]`)? Since what you want to avoid is a line from `f2` printing not it assigning.

Comment: @EtanReisner Not particularly no, just thought i'd do it differently than usual. Anyway i've updated :)