# bash : calculate number using result of another file

Tags: bash

I have two text log files, the first one `file1` is in format :

```
domain=yahoo       user=tom
domain=apple       user=mary
domain=apple       user=tom
domaine=facebook   user=kevin
    ...
```

and the second one `file2` :

```
name=tony apply=yes
name=tony apply=yes
name=mary apply=yes
name=tony apply=yes
name=tom  apply=yes
...
```

Now I want to get the total line occurrence from the second file where domain of the user equals "yahoo", how can I do it?

Comment: You mean where the `user=` value is equal to a `name=` value in the other file whose `domain=` value is `yahoo`?

Comment: I'd use awk for this job.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, exactly

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @anubhava Output should be a number (integer), for my example it should print "1" for "yahoo", and "1" for "apple" because "tom" is not in file 2

Comment: don't forget the `join` command.

Comment: Isn't `name=tom  apply=yes` line there in file 2?

Comment: I count two records in `file2` where the user maps to `domain=apple`.  Why is the count for `apple` not supposed to be 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# put the name that belongs to the domain=yahoo in a file
grep -n "domain=yahoo" file1 | cut -d = -f3 > result
# initialize counter
total=0
# loop over file with names and increment the counter with the number of matches
for name in $(cat result); do
    ((total+=$(grep -n "$name" file2 | wc -l)))
done
```

@drvtiny pointed me in the direction of another (shorter) version:

```
grep "domain=yahoo" file1 |     # search for the pattern \
    cut -d = -f3 |              # get the third field (name) from the output \
    grep -v '^$'  |             # remove any blank lines that might creep in \
    sort |                      # sort the result, so we can see duplicates \
    uniq > result               # remove duplicates and write the results to a file

grep --count --file=result file2
```

`grep --file=FILE` will get the pattern from the mentioned file, one at a line
`--count` returns the number of matched lines

Comment: Thanks but this is not working, it shows "let : not found"

Comment: It's still not working but you made me know how to do it, thanks

Comment: Great that you got it working! See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/385532/143230) for how to use different ways to increment a variable, if you're interested. Some ways may not work on all versions of Bash.

Comment: Instead of the for-cycle you may use simple grep -c -f result!
And you must sort and uniq after cut -d = -f3, because you will get a lot of duplicates in the result file otherwise.

Comment: @drvtiny Thanks for suggesting improvements! I have updated my answer, what do you think?

Comment: I think, "echo" is unnecessary here. All other code is good
Change echo $(grep --count --file=result file2) to simply grep --count --file=result file2 and you will be done :)

Comment: @drvtiny You're right. I was somehow under the impression that I needed the `echo` to return the result from a script and use it to assign it to a variable. But that seems not to be the case. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The irregular input file format complicates matters slightly.  Usually, you *either* have a static number of columns in a specified order, or a sequence of keyword=value pairs in arbitrary order.  Assuming the columns are fixed, we can simply ignore the keyword= part with a simple `substr()` call.

```
awk 'NR==FNR && $1 == "domain=yahoo" { a[substr($2,6)]=1; next }
    substr($1,6) in a { x++; next } END { print x }' file1 file2
```

The general structure of the script is a straightforward implementation of the common `NR==FNR` idiom.  There is a large number of these questions on Stack Overflow; see e.g. [Comparing fields of two files in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631141/comparing-fields-of-two-files-in-awk) for an example.

Comment: The output is 1 for `yahoo` and 2 for `apple`.  I don't see how your example files would produce a 1 for `apple`?

Answer (score -1):

My /tmp/log is:

```
domain=yahoo       user=tom
domain=apple       user=mary
domain=apple       user=tom
domain=facebook   user=kevin
domain=apple   user=tony
```

My /tmp/name is:

```
name=tony apply=yes
name=tony apply=yes
name=mary apply=yes
name=tony apply=yes
name=tom  apply=yes
name=kevin  apply=yes
```

The script.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
DOMAIN=$1
LOG_FILE=$2
NAME_FILE=$3
REGEXP="$(sed -nr "/domain=$DOMAIN/s%^.*user=([^[:space:]]+).*$%\1%p" "$LOG_FILE" | sort | uniq | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's%|$%%')"
[[ $REGEXP ]] || {
 echo 'No such domain in log file' >&2
 exit 1
}
egrep -c "name=(${REGEXP})([[:space:]]|$)" "$NAME_FILE"
```

Run the script with arguments:

```
./script.sh apple /tmp/log /tmp/name
```

And you'll get this result:

```
5
```